# How to add Firebase Functions v8 to a Swift iOS project and use Codable in httpsCallable?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a Swift 5.5 iOS project that already contains Firebase 7.x and uses Firebase Functions. I just upgraded to 8.13.0, because I want to use `Codable` support in Firebase Functions.

I added Firebase through the Swift Package manager and included Firebase Functions in my source code using:

```
import FirebaseFunctions
```

However, when I want to call:

```
  func httpsCallable<Request: Encodable,
    Response: Decodable>(_ name: String,
                         requestAs: Request.Type = Request.self,
                         responseAs: Response.Type = Response.self)
```

I get an error saying that it doesn't find this method.

Upon inspecting the packages, I discovered that the function I want to call is defined in `FirebaseFunctionsSwift` in a file called `Callable+Codable` .

This exists in my project as you can see:

[image]

However when I add `import FirebaseFunctionsSwift` to my source file I get the following error:

```
No such module 'FirebaseFunctionsSwift'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add FirebaseFunctionsSwift-Beta framework to the build target:

[image]